# Dropdown list don't get data from API. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in JS and have questions. I created UI. I need create a dropdown list. Below it is table and after below it is submit button. Then user will click on a button, user will get new table based on his choice.
I started implement and successfully get data from API for my table. But when I tried add data in my dropdown list - I have no data.

My code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Table, Spin, Select } from 'antd';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useFetch } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';
import AccountType from 'components/AccountType';

const MoveProperty = ({ onSelectingItems }) => {
  const [data, isLoading] = useFetch(apiService.moveProperty);
  const [dataDrop] = useFetch(apiService.getAllClents);
  const [selectedAccountTypes, setSelectedItems] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
      <Select loading={isLoading}>
        {dataDrop && dataDrop.map(({ id, name }) => (
          <Select.Option key={id} value={id} title={name}>{name}</Select.Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <AccountType onSelectingItems={setSelectedItems} />
      <Table
        key="id"
        bordered="true"
        rowKey="id"
        dataSource={data}
        rowSelection={{ onChange: onSelectingItems }}
        pagination={false}
      >
        <Table.Column title="Account Type" dataIndex="accountType" />
        <Table.Column title="Account Number" dataIndex="accountNumber" />
        <Table.Column title="Account ID" dataIndex="accountId" />
        <Table.Column title="Account Name" dataIndex="accountName" />
      </Table>
    </Spin>
  );
};

MoveProperty.propTypes = {
  onSelectingItems: PropTypes.func,
};

MoveProperty.defaultProps = {
  onSelectingItems: () => { },
};

export default MoveProperty;
```

Here is a problem:

```
      <Select loading={isLoading}>
        {dataDrop && dataDrop.map(({ id, name }) => (
          <Select.Option key={id} value={id} title={name}>{name}</Select.Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
```

And Last question. Now I don't have space between dropdown list and table. How I could add it?
Attached screen:
[image]

Comment: So it's `apiService.getAllClents` without an `i`, and it returns an array containing the clients array as first and only element?

Comment: From API returning array with several parameters: Client ID, Property ID, Property Name, Client Name. But in this list Client Name is enough. Not One element. All clients which we have

Comment: Yeah, but are you sure it's supposed to be `const [dataDrop] = useFetch(apiService.getAllClents);` and not for instance `const dataDrop = useFetch(apiService.getAllClients);`

Comment: No, I'm not sure. It's my implementation. I tried yours 2nd version. After this changes my page doesn't open